# ngGridCsvExportPlugin not working in IE

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

For some reason CSV export is not working IE. perfectly working in firefox and chrome.

I have used ngGridCsvExportPlugin to perform the export.

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: 'rows', enableColumnResize: true
      ,plugins: [new ngGridCsvExportPlugin()],
      showFooter: true
  };
```

complete code is in:

http://plnkr.co/edit/PUetI8JOF6gkwFKoV303

Not sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: Not working in IE 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following update to your plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/bzxEo0XtK4AlI4krLSa5

```
        if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {//check for IE
            var e = angular.element("<span class=\"csv-data-link-span\"><button ng-click='exportIE()'>CSV Export</button></span>");
            $compile(e)(scope);
            fp.append(e);
        }else{
          var csvDataLinkHtml = "<span class=\"csv-data-link-span\">";
          csvDataLinkHtml += "<br><a href=\"data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,";
          csvDataLinkHtml += encodeURIComponent(csvData);
          csvDataLinkHtml += "\" download=\"Export.csv\">CSV Export</a></br></span>";
          fp.append(csvDataLinkHtml);
        }
```

Since ng-grid doesnt have access to angular services, I injected it ($compile) into your controller and then passed it through the plugin constructor.